# In Inversify, why to prefer Constructor/Factory injection over toDynamicValue?

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, inversifyjs

In [InversifyJS](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS), are there any specific advantages of following the approaches outlined in [factory injection guide](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/factory_injection.md) and [constructor injection guide](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/constructor_injection.md)  for injecting factories and constructors respectively over just using [toDynamicValue](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/value_injection.md).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### toConstructor

If you use a `toConstructor` you will be able to pass arguments to the constructor but you won't be able to resolve those arguments (unless you inject them as well).

```
container.bind<interfaces.Newable<Katana>>("Newable<Katana>")
         .toConstructor<Katana>(Katana);
```

### toDynamicValue

If you use a `toDynamicValue` you will be able to pass constructor arguments to the constructor and resolve those arguments using the `context`.

```
container.bind<Katana>("Katana")
        .toDynamicValue((context: interfaces.Context) => {
             return new Katana(context.container.get("SomeDependency")); 
        });
```

### toFactory

If you use a `toFactory` you will be able to pass constructor arguments to the constructor and resolve those arguments using the `context` but you will also be able to produce different outputs based on factory arguments.

```
container.bind<interfaces.Factory<Weapon>>("Factory<Weapon>")
         .toFactory<Weapon>((context: interfaces.Context) => {
             return (throwable: boolean) => {
                 if (throwable) {
                     return context.container.getTagged<Weapon>(
                         "Weapon", "throwable", true
                     );
                 } else {
                     return context.container.getTagged<Weapon>(
                         "Weapon", "throwable", false
                     );
                 }
             };
         });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear and lucid explanation. Also thank you for all the awesome work on inversify.