# Inversify toFactory vs toDynamicValue

Tags: javascript, ioc-container, inversifyjs

[This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867437/in-inversify-why-to-prefer-constructor-factory-injection-over-todynamicvalue) shows [examples from the documentation](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/factory_injection.md) but doesn't explain practical difference between InversifyJS `toFactory` and `toDynamicValue`

`toDynamicValue` accepts factory function while `toFactory` accepts higher-order factory function. But `toDynamicValue` could return factory function as a value, too.

Can they serve same purpose and how can their behaviour be different?

How do `Bar` and `Baz` differ in this example?

```
container.bind('Bar').toDynamicValue(
  context => fooName => context.container.getNamed(Foo, fooName)
)

container.bind('Baz').toFactory(
  context => fooName => context.container.getNamed(Foo, fooName)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

As I see it the dynamic value syntax is the one you pass into any value / lambda that results in creating an instance.

The Factory syntax results in a factory where you also get the context. From the context you can get the container and use service-location to resolve other objects you need construct your object instance. So its a indirection supplying the context and therefore the container too.